# plane given with a line on it -> build a rectangle in the plane with the line as the diagonal of the rectangle (in 3D)

Tags: geometry

(Everything's in 3D) Firstly a plane is given. On this plane I'm drawing a line. The beginning and ending point of the line is given therefore. What I have to do is to use the line as the diagonal of the rectangle to create the rectangle. For this I just need the other two missing points which are also in the very same plane I've got.

How can I determine the missing two points?

In 2D for example if you have like point B (6|4) and C (1|2) then you can conclude that A is on (1|4) and D is on (6|2).

But I struggle to find a method/algorithm to do so in a 3D world.

PS: If I used the wrong tag please tell me another suggestion, thx!

Comment: There is infinite number of rectangles with the same diagonal. (Note - in 2D case too, you just restrict with axis-aligned rectangles)

Comment: @MBo Thank you very much for the explanation but I thought that I could use the same restriction in 3D too. Other than that I actually don't know how I could restrict it.

Comment: I proposed a variant

Answer (score 1):

To show that infinite number of rectangles with common diagonal does exist in the same plane:

You have vertices `A` and `C`,  and plane normal vector `n`, and want to determine vertices `B` and `D`.
Let `B = (bx, by, bz)` (unknown)

Condition of perpendicularity of `AB` and `BC` edges: dot product of vectors is zero.

```
 (bx-ax) * (bx-сx) + (by-ay) * (by-сy) + (bz-az) * (bz-сz) = 0
```

Condition of "B lies in the plane": dot product of `AB` and normal is zero

```
 (bx-ax) * nx + (by-ay) * ny + (bz-az) * nz = 0
```

So you have **two** linear equations for **three** unknowns `bx, by, bz` - infinite number of solutions.

Perhaps you might have some additional condition/restriction to define solution uniquely (as axis-aligned rectangle in your 2d example)

**Edit:**
Arbitrary possible variant: let `AB` edge is parallel to `OXY` plane, so it is perpendicular to `OZ` axis, and the third equation is

```
 (bx-ax) * 0 + (by-ay) * 0 + (bz-az) * 1 = 0, so
 (bz - az) = 0
```

and you can substitute this expression and solve system for two unknowns `bx` and `by`

```
 (bx-ax) * (bx-сx) + (by-ay) * (by-сy) = 0
 (bx-ax) * nx + (by-ay) * ny = 0
```

Comment: I tried to solve this linear equation system but came to no conclusion. After substituting the third equation in the second one there is no nz dependency left and since the normal vector to the plane has just a contribution to nz there is no solution as I've understood.

Comment: I explicitly write new system. Solution just does not depend on nz in this case